# Styling issues on simple code between Bootstrap ~3.7 and latest Bootstrap (4)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I downloaded some pretty simple code off Coursera for a Responsive Web Design class to mess around with toggling navbars, and with what seems to be Bootstrap approx 3.7 (came with the class code), the pretty basic code runs fine.

However, with a fresh download of the latest Bootstrap, the code doesn't display correctly, I can't figure out what the issue is. I've attached screenshots. Note that in the incorrectly displayed ones, clicking the little flat button will display the other elements, but only for about half a second before disappearing. Multiple other students have had the exact same issue and posted about it in the forums, but none of the moderators or mentors have been able to correctly advise, so I'm praying that you guys can help!

What is the issue here? Is it classes/class properties that don't exist in the latest Bootstrap?

The correct display for the page (how it looks with BS ~3.7):

[image]

How it looks with BS 4.2, incorrectly displayed:

[image]

How it looks with a new Bootswatch theme (Slate), incorrectly displayed:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <title></title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and     media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file://     -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script     src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">    </script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Edward MonteVerde</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>

          <!-- here is the dropdown menu -->

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" 
                aria-expanded="false">Contact <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Skype</a></li>
              <!-- can you add another item to the dropdown? -->
            </ul>
          </li>

          <!-- the end of the dropdown menu -->

        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:** If paid professors and/or mentors cannot tell you how to fix this very basic problem, stop paying them and try to recover any money you've already given them.

You usually cannot upgrade "major" versions of a tool without making significant changes to your app/code. This is a general rule for anything which uses version numbers (eg. most software, and especially anything on `npm`). The "major" version is the left most number in the version number.

v2.3
v3.1
v4.21

> Read more about semantic versioning here: https://semver.org/

In your case, you are going from major version 3 to major version 4. A quick look at the [bootstrap navbar in version 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navbar/), lots of things have changed compared to the code you posted. I created a fiddle with the updated code (note, resize the preview panel to see it switch from hamburger to expanded).

https://jsfiddle.net/m8gfhr95/

Here's a basic snippet. Take note of the classes on the `nav` element, as well as the `li` and `a` elements:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it classes/class properties that don't exist in the latest Bootstrap?

Yes. Between major version changes (3 to 4), there are major updates as well. For example, Bootstrap 4 uses flex for Grid System instead of float, and classes names have also changed (`pull-right` is now `float-right`).

This means that we shouldn't expect snippets from previous versions to still work in the newer ones, and therefore they need to be adapted.

If this example is a default snippet of Bootstrap 3, consider looking at the version 4 one instead – generally the examples in the documentation stay the same. Otherwise consider looking at [the migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#navs) for `nav` between these versions, though your best bet might still be starting with a Bootstrap 4 snippet and adapting it to match the design.